# Angular app is not defined when adding a custom filter outside of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Trying to follow some examples, but I get **app is not defined**

app.js

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
   var app = angular.module("deviceManagement",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
}());
```

So I have HOPING to be able to use or attach to "app"

I have a controller js file

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
angular
    .module("deviceManagement")
    .controller("DeviceListCtrl",
    ProductListCtrl);

function ProductListCtrl($http, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.devices = [];

    deviceList();


    function deviceList() {

      //..........
    }

  }
} ());
```

THEN RIGHT UNDER the ABOVE CODE I DO THIS

```
app.filter('deviceStatus', function () {

    var deviceStatusLookup = {
        1: "New Device",
        2: "Activated",
        3: "Unactivated"
    };

    return function (statusId) {
        var output = deviceStatusLookup[statusId];
        return output;
    }
});
```

Error on page console

```
deviceListCtrl.js:73 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

Comment: i think you should use app.controller in your deviceListCtrl.js in place of angular.controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have included the app.js file.

Also, I would change the below:

```
app.filter('deviceStatus', function () {
```

to this:

```
angular
    .module("deviceManagement")
    .filter('deviceStatus', function () {
```

It is a good idea to not use var app and to just refer to the module, e.g. angular.module("deviceManagement"). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957280/angularjs-best-practices-for-module-declaration).

Comment: Yep @ScottL this one is definitely the best approach.

Comment: Thanks , this make sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Well in you case the issue is that in here:

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
   var app = angular.module("deviceManagement",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
}());
```

You have `app` in a lambda function, and it exists just in there.

#### To make it works you should have:

```
(function (window) {
   "use strict";
   var app = angular.module("deviceManagement",['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
   window.app = app || {};
}(window));
```

So here we are injecting the `window` element in the lambda so you can define `app` globally (`window.app = app || {}`).

> Note: Consider that the window.app approach is not the best.

Probably the `angular.module("deviceManagement")` syntax is the best way to go, in a way to have your code more modular.

Comment: 1. don't you mean IIFE? (not lambda)   2.  What is a better approach?

Comment: thanks @CodingAway i have to confess you that i didn't know that the pattern name of  the `(function(){ ... })()` was IIFE. The syntax `function()` is for anonymous functions and so I called `lambda`

Comment: The best approach as @ScottL suggested is the `angular.module("deviceManagement")` one but it was not explaining why you were receiving  `app is not defined` .